# Storing MP4 Files in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I am currently considering whether I should be storing media in an apache cassandra database. The use case is that the site will be taking uploads from users for insurance claims and will need to store the files so that they cannot be accessed outside the correct permissions and at the same time they need to be able to be streamed. If I store them on a file system, I have to deal with redundancy backups and so on using file system based old tech. I am not really interested in dealing with a CDN because many of them are expensive but also I the permissions to the whether you can view the content depends on information in the app such as which adjuster is assigned to the case and so on. In addition I want to stream the files rather than require download and view which would be the default mode with requests against a CDN. If I put them in cassandra it will handle the replication, storage and I can stream the binary data out of the database to the user with integrated permissions. What I am concerned about is if I will run into problems with cassandra rows having huge HD video files that are sometimes 1 to 2 hours long (testimony).

I am interested in the recommendations of Cassandra users concerning this issue. How would to solve the problem. Any lessons you have learned that I can benefit from. Would you suggest anything specific about the video tables if I go with cassandra storage? Is there any CDN that will stream, not require download, allow me to plug in permissions and at the same time be open source?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is definitely not designed and should not be used as an object store. I've worked on plenty of use cases where Cassandra was used as the metadata store alongside the object store/CDN and can complement them quite nicely.

Check out KillrVideo for inspiration: https://killrvideo.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good key-value usecase for Streaming LOB support in Oracle NoSQL Database. You might want to look at this - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuide/lobapi.html